# In the Incarnations of Immortality Series, who really created the Universe?

Tags: fantasy-genre, piers-anthony

In "With a Tangled Skein" we learn that Clotho, the youngest aspect of Fate, is responsible for gathering raw void and spinning it into souls, which contain a mix of good and evil.

When Niobe is learning to be Clotho, she is told by the other aspects of Fate that God created the Universe from the Void.

However, in "Bearing an Hourglass", it is hinted that other belief systems have their own models of existence, and in "For Love of Evil", we learn that God's office is actually just another incarnation (of Good), and that JHVH (the Jewish Diety) was another such office holder, one who had a much more amicable relationship with Satan (Incarnation of Evil).

The suggestion of multiple frames of operation (presumably Buddhism and Hindu would have their own systems) in this magical universe begs the ultimate question - if God exists but only became God by ascending to the position, then how did the universe come into being?

Comment: Not the answer you want to hear, I suspect, but, as far as I recall, the series doesn't answer that question.  There are lots of beliefs (and, as Molly Malone points out in the first novel, belief DOES affect things), but I don't recall the books ever conclusively answering your question, just offering hints and possibilities.  That said, I haven't read 'Under a Velvet Cloak', so perhaps there are answers there.

Comment: Just finished 'Under a Velvet Cloak' -- no help; it identifies the source of the incarnations, but using two more beings, and primal chaos.  Nor real answer as to where they (and Chaos itself) come from, although I suppose the concept of Chaos always existing is implied.  That said, there is still no indication of where the true origin of everything is, just the source 'as far back as they can see / know.' (There's even a creation vision with Magic and Science existences (and a hybrid universe), but no indication of the true creating force behind it all.)